# I can't get the Math right for this salary code

Tags: c#

I can't get the math right for this code. Im trying to output a salary that doubles each day for up to 14 days. For Example: on day 1 the output should be 1; on day 2 the output should be 2; day 3 output should be 4; and on day 14 the output should be 1050.

```
using System;

public class Salary
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int salary = 1;
        int w;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of days worked: ");
        w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int wage = 1; wage < w + 1; wage++)
        {
            salary = wage * salary;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The salary is: ${0}.00", salary);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close....");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: VS comes with a powerful debugger.  Learn It. Use It. Love It.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through it, and looking at the results on each iteration? Ideally, write it down on a piece of paper...

Comment: Check out `Math.Pow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think salary don't get double every day but increases by 100% of basic salary by everyday. As you said, base salary is 1. First day it is 1, second day 2, third day 3 (would have been 4 in case of double). Please correct if my understanding is wrong. I changed your code to below as per my understanding.

*And output of amount earner on 14th day is 105.00*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int salary = 1;
            int w;
            int amountEarned = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of days worked: ");
            w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int wage = 1; wage < w + 1; wage++)
            {
                var currentDaySalary = (salary * ((wage*100)/100));
                amountEarned += currentDaySalary;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The salary is: ${0}.00", amountEarned);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close....");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Comment: He Does State "For Example: on day 1 the output should be 1; on day 2 the output should be 2; day 3 output should be 4;"

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int wage = 0; wage < w; wage++)
    {
        salary = salary * 2;
    }
```

Comment: `salaray` looks kinda wrong? Great example of the benefits of the `*=` operator ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So what you're really doing is multiplying salary by 2 to a power (from 0 to 13). Something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int salary = 1;
    int w;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of days worked: ");
    w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    salary *= Math.Pow(2, Math.Min(w - 1, 13));

    Console.WriteLine("The salary is: ${0}.00", salary);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close....");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```